# Neado kaj "nek"

Tags: negation

Laŭ [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neado.html#i-nzv):

> *Nek* signifas “kaj ankaŭ ne”, “kaj ankaŭ nenio“ k.s. Oni uzas *nek*, se oni jam uzis *ne* aŭ tabelvorton je NENI, kaj volas nei ankoraŭ
>   ion.

Ekzemple:

> *Mi ne renkontis lin, **nek** lian fraton. = ...kaj ankaŭ ne lian fraton.*

Aldone, [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/nek_nek.html) klarigas:

> Ordinara *nek* signifas “kaj ankaŭ ne”, “kaj ankaŭ neniu” k.s.
>   Plurobla *nek* signifas “kaj ne”. Kombinita *nek* estas do egala al
>   *kaj... kaj* plus neado

Ekzemple:

> *Mi renkontis **nek** lin, **nek** lian fraton. = Mi kaj ne renkontis lin, kaj ne renkontis lian fraton.*

En Tekstaro aperas la jena frazo:

> [...] kiam ne estis nek libroj nek oleo kaj “ornato”, tiam li ne povis
>   nek volis altuŝi la aferon

La frazo ŝajnas al mi malĝusta kaj laŭ mia opinio devus esti *kiam estis nek libroj nek oleo*... aŭ *kiam ne estis libroj nek oleo*... Tamen, mi trovas konfuziga la klarigon de PMEG, ke oni uzas *nek*, se oni jam uzis *ne*, kiel okazas en la supra frazo de Tekstaro.

Do, mia demando estas: Ĉu la frazo ... *kiam ne estis nek libroj nek oleo* ... estas ĝusta aŭ malĝusta kaj kial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas du manieroj uzi *nek*. Unu estas la kombino *nek X nek Y*, kio signifas *ne X kaj ankaŭ ne Y*. La alia uzmaniero de *nek* estas la unuopa *nek*, kiu ĉiam aperas post io neita, ekzemple *Mi ne renkontis lin nek lian fraton*, kio signifas *Mi ne renkontis lin kaj ankaŭ ne lian fraton*.

La citita frazo el la Tekstaro estas erara. Oni povus korekti ĝin aŭ per la forigo de *ne* post *kiam*, aŭ per forigo de la unua *nek*. Ambaŭ manieroj korekti ĝin kondukas al la sama signifo.

Answer (score 0):

Laŭ [Fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/ekzercaro.html#ekzerco28) *nek* signifas

> (de) weder ... noch
>
> (en) neither ... nor

kiel en

> kie estas postulata nek laboro, nek mono.<sup>1</sup>

En la frazo en Tekstaro

> ... kiam ne estis nek libroj nek oleo ...

estas duobla neado. La [kompleta frazo](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=vojaghimpresoj&id=bq106&ignorifremdajhojn=0&uzistreketojn=0&uskle=1&serchesprimo=nek#bq106) estas

> Sed li tuj revenis tre ofendita kaj klarigis malkontente, ke kiam ne estis nek libroj nek oleo kaj "ornato", tiam li ne povis nek volis altuŝi la aferon – estis honto nur eĉ proponi ion tielan!

La aŭtoro verŝajne uzas

> ... **ne** estis **nek** ... **nek** ...

por fortigi malkontenton pri la manko en la senco de *eĉ ne estis*.

Por miaj germanaj oreloj duobla neado sonas erare. Sed duobla neado en multaj lingvoj indikas fortan deklaron. Tial mi ne dirus, ke duobla neado estas absolute erara. Tamen mi ne uzus ĝin.

Do mi konsentas kun vi: devus esti *... kiam estis nek libroj nek oleo ...* aŭ *... kiam ne estis libroj nek oleo*.

---

<sup>1 Zamenhof en la Dua Libro de l' lingvo Internacia</sup>

Comment: Via respondo ne estas tre klara pri ĉu la frazo estas erara aŭ ne. Unue vi diras ke ĝi “povus esti uzata por fortigi malkontenton” sed poste diras ke ĝi devus esti io alia. Ĝi ŝajnas al mi ja erara, kaj tial teknike ĝi ne havas la fortigan sencon kiun la aŭtoro verŝajne celis. Anstataŭe ĝi kreas duoblan neadon. http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neado.html#i-87t

Comment: @Olafant: [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/nek_nek.html) klarigas, ke _nek_ signifas "kaj ankaŭ ne" se temas pri ordinara _nek_ (sola _nek_), kaj ĝi signifas “kaj ne” se temas pri plurobla _nek_ (_nek... nek_). En tio mi ne vidas malharmonion.

Comment: @Olafant: Tiu frazo ŝajnas al mi ĝusta, kaj estas alia maniero diri _Mi renkontis nek lin, nek lian fraton_. Mi dubus pri ĝia ĝusteco, se ĝi estus _Mi **ne** renkontis nek lin, nek lian fraton_, simile kiel mi dubas pri _kiam ne estis nek libroj nek oleo_.

Comment: @Olafant: Mi pensas ke en la frazo _Mi kaj ne renkontis lin, kaj ne renkontis lian fraton_, la unua _kaj_ estas [emfaza _kaj_](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/kaj_kaj.html), same kiel en la frazo _Petro kaj fumas kaj drinkas_. Kaj la unua frazo kaj la dua estas ĝusta Esperanto. La strukturo _kaj… kaj_ estas kvazaŭ la malo de _nek... nek_.

Comment: @Vidamuzo Ah, ok. I didn't see that, but how to explain *nek ... nek* in Esperanto other than with *not ... as well as not ...*. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

La ordinara formo estas ... nek A, nek B` kaj signifas *neniu el la kazoj, A aŭ B*.

> Mi vidis **nek** aŭtobuson, **nek** taksion, por atingi la malsanalujon.

- (bg) нито ... нито ...
- (de) weder ... noch ...
- (en) neither ... nor ...
- (fr) (ne .....) ni ... ni ...

Kiel vi vidas la bulgara kaj franca same uzas ripetitan adverbon.

La signifo estas:

> Mi ne vidis aŭtobuson, kaj ankaŭ ne vidis taksion.
>
> Mi vidis neniun aŭtobuson, kaj ankaŭ neniun taksion.

La lasta kun bona akcento pri la objekto.

Comment: Eble la franca estas konfuza ekzemplo, ĉar teorie oni devus aldoni ankaŭ la vorton “ne”, do la plena frazo estus “je ne vois ni bus ni taxi”.

Comment: @NeilRoberts jes, en la franca oni uzas _ne-pas_ kaj _ne-ni-ni_.